# premake5 add generated files to vstudio project

Tags: premake

I have overridden the onProject function for the vs2012 action which generates some cpp files and then tries to include them in the project

```
--cant override the generateProject directly
--so have to override at the action level
premake.override( premake.action._list.vs2012, 'onProject', function(base, prj)
      
    if premake.project.iscpp(prj) then
        
        --generate files  
        --print( "Generating extra files ...")
        local extraFiles = mine.getExtraFiles(prj)

        for _,file in ipairs( extraFiles ) do
            p.generate( file, nil, mine.generateExtraFile )                
            mine.addFileToSources(file)
        end                            
    end

    --Generate regular stuff
    base(prj)      
end)


function mine.getExtraFiles(prj)
    local extraFiles = {}
    --works out what files to generate and add relevant info to table
    
    return extraFiles
end

--this function is passed as a callback to premake.generate
function mine.generateExtraFile(extraFile)
    --write contents of file
end
```

This is the function that attempts to add each generated file to the project

```
function mine.addFileToSources(extraFile)
    local prj = extraFile.prj
    local cfg = extraFile.cfg

    local groups  = premake.vstudio.vc2010.categorizeSources(prj)       
    local compiledFiles = groups.ClCompile or {} 
    
    --create a new file config for generated file
    local filename = path.join(extraFile.location, extraFile.filename)
    local fcfg = premake.fileconfig.new( filename, prj)

    premake.fileconfig.addconfig(fcfg, cfg)
       
    --add the config to the project's sources
    table.insert(compiledFiles, fcfg)
    compiledFiles[filename] = fcfg

    --add to the projects source tree
    --this bit is copied from premake.project.getsourcetree
 
        -- The tree represents the logical source code tree to be displayed
        -- in the IDE, not the physical organization of the file system. So
        -- virtual paths are used when adding nodes.

        -- If the project script specifies a virtual path for a file, disable
        -- the logic that could trim out empty root nodes from that path. If
        -- the script writer wants an empty root node they should get it.

        local flags
        if fcfg.vpath ~= fcfg.relpath then
            flags = { trim = false }
        end
          
        -- Virtual paths can overlap, potentially putting files with the same
        -- name in the same folder, even though they have different paths on
        -- the underlying filesystem. The tree.add() call won't overwrite
        -- existing nodes, so provide the extra logic here. Start by getting
        -- the parent folder node, creating it if necessary.
        
        local tr = premake.project.getsourcetree(prj)
        local parent = premake.tree.add(tr, path.getdirectory(fcfg.vpath), flags)
        
        local node = premake.tree.insert(parent, premake.tree.new(path.getname(fcfg.vpath)))

        -- Pass through value fetches to the file configuration
        setmetatable(node, { __index = fcfg })                        
end
```

For the most part - this all works:
The files are generated correctly and to correct location
The files are also included in the vcxproj file correctly

My problem is that the vcxproj.filters file is not being generated.
When I run premake I get this error:

```
Generating myproject.vcxproj.filters...Error: [string "src/actions/vstudio/vs2010_vcxproj_filters...."]:82: attempt to index field 'parent' (a nil value)
```

which corresponds to the function premake.vstudio.vc2010.filterGroup(prj, groups, group)
I get that the new fcfg I created needs to have a parent but I can't work out where or what I should be adding it to.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT 1**

I've got things working by adding this line to the end of function mine.addFileToSources(extraFile)

```
fcfg.parent = parent
```

This gives the file config a parent node so everything works out but I feel kinda dirty doing this so I'll look at following Citron's advice

**EDIT 2**

Overriding the bakefiles was much cleaner and neater. It wasn't  as straightforward as Citron's code since I needed the information from the baked files in order to carry out my file generation but I am now confident that my code is correct and will possibly work with other exporters than vstudio too.

Here's my new code:

```
premake.override( premake.oven, 'bakeFiles', function(base, prj)

    --bake the files as normal
    local bakedFiles = base(prj)

    if premake.project.iscpp(prj) then
    
        --gather information about what files to generate and how
        local extraFiles = mine.getExtraFiles(prj, bakedFiles)
                              
        for _,file in ipairs( extraFiles ) do
        
            --do the generation
            premake.generate( file, file.extension, mine.generateExtraFile )                            
             
            --add the new files 
            local filename = premake.filename(file, file.extension)
            table.insert(file.cfg.files, filename)
       
            -- This should be the first time I've seen this file, start a new
            -- file configuration for it. Track both by key for quick lookups
            -- and indexed for ordered iteration.
            assert( bakedFiles[filename] == nil )
                                                                       
            local fcfg = premake.fileconfig.new(filename, file.prj)
            bakedFiles[filename] = fcfg
            table.insert(bakedFiles, fcfg)
       
            premake.fileconfig.addconfig( bakedFiles[filename], file.cfg)                                       
        end 

        --sort the baked files again - since we have added to them
        table.sort(bakedFiles, function(a,b)
            return a.vpath < b.vpath
        end)
               
    end 
    return bakedFiles
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is with your code (a bit too much to read, and not enough time :p) but if you just want to add some generated files to your project tree, I would advise you to override `premake.oven.bakeFiles` instead.

This is what I used to add files generated by Qt in my addon. See `premake.extensions.qt.customBakeFiles` on https://github.com/dcourtois/premake-qt/blob/master/qt.lua

Basically in the `bakeFiles` override, you can just browse your projects, and insert files in the list easily. Then, if those added files need some custom configuration, you can then override `premake.fileconfig.addconfig`. See `premake.extensions.qt.customAddFileConfig` in the aforementioned addon.

In this `addconfig` override, you'll have access to the files and you will be able to modify their configuration object: you can add custom build rules, special options, etc.

It's not a direct answer to your specific question, but I hope it will help you achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks - that's good advice. I'll look into overriding bakefiles instead. I actually have now got it working my way but it seems a bit hacky so I'm not convinced

Comment: Yep, I read the "copied from premake.project.getsourcetree" comment in your code, and generally speaking if you need to do that, it's not the right way :)